# How to upload an audio file to server in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, networking

I have an error uploading an mp3 audio file to the server using [Fast Android Networking library](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking). The request is sent successfully, but the server response is always ***false*** (note that the server response with only one boolean parameter which is false only if there's a problem with the uploaded file). I try to send the same request with the same file using postman and the response was ***true***!

Here's the code I used for uploading the file

```
    public static void uploadSound(final Context context, final String std_id, final String story_id, final String task_id, final File file) {
    
    AndroidNetworking.upload(UploadSound)
            .addMultipartParameter("std_id", std_id)
            .addMultipartParameter("story_id", story_id)
            .addMultipartParameter("task_id", task_id)
            .addMultipartFile("audio_blob", file)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("UPLOADING", "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        boolean booleanResponse = response.getBoolean("result");
                        if (booleanResponse)
                            Toast.makeText(context, "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to upload!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception1", "onResponse: ", e);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to upload!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(ANError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Something wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Exception1", "onResponse: ", error);
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the [postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q34tD.png) and [Function's parameters values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyVjG.png).

Please let me know if you need further information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try use this code

```
Map<String, File> multiPartFileMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (!PathHolder.equals("")) {
        multiPartFileMap.put("attachment", new File(PathHolder));
    }

    Map<String, String> parames = new HashMap<>();
    parames.put("name", name);
    parames.put("email", email);
    parames.put("message", details);
    parames.put("subject", subject);

        AndroidNetworking.upload(URLs.CONTACT)
                .addMultipartFile(multiPartFileMap)
                .addQueryParameter(parames)
                .addHeaders(FamousFunction.getHeaders(this))
                .setTag("Contact With Us")
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .setExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build()
                .setUploadProgressListener((bytesUploaded, totalBytes) -> {
                    // do anything with progress
                })
                .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                    }
                });
```

//Header

```
   public static Map<String, String> getHeaders(Context context) {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
     headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.put("Accept-Language", sharedPrefrences.getLanguage(context));
    headers.put("Authorization", sharedPrefrences.getApiToken(context));
     return headers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the correct variable name `st_id` instead of `std_id`.